# Refactored with Resharper and bugs were introduced, why?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I had a method which I thought was pretty over the top with if statements, I decided to refactor it with the help of Resharper and later found out it was the cause of a lot of bugs I was having.

```
private bool isValid(User user)
{
    if (user == null)
        return false;
    if (user.IsBot)
        return true;
    if (user.GetClient() == null)
        return false;
    if (user.GetClient().GetData() == null)
        return false;
    if (user.GetClient().GetData().CurrentRoomId != _room.RoomId)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I refactored it to this

```
private bool isValid(User user)
{
    return user?.GetClient() != null && user.GetClient().GetData() != null && user.GetClient().GetData().CurrentRoomId == _room.RoomId;
}
```

After returning the refactored version to the original all bugs vanished. Just for self improvement purposes, could somebody tell me what I did wrong? I can't see anything but clearly it broke a lot of things so it must have made some difference.

Comment: For example, refactored version misses `IsBot` check completely.

Comment: As you can see from your refactor, the original version was A LOT more readable. The goal of your code is not to be as short as possible but to be readable

Comment: Your Unit Tests should raise errors before you even notice any bugs ... well only if you have unit tests

Answer (score 5):

The original version was more readable and during your refactor, you introduced a bug. The `IsBot` check is missing.

You could refactor the method to this:

```
private bool isValid(User user)
{
    if (user == null)
        return false;
    if (user.IsBot)
        return true;
    return user.GetClient()?.GetData()?.CurrentRoomId == _room.RoomId;
}
```

Still readable, but shorter and more to the point.

Comment: Why not `user?.IsBot` and `return user?.GetClient()?...`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Because you can't just do `if(user?.IsBot)`, because the result of that is a `Nullable<bool>` and you will get a compiler error. You would need this code instead: `if(((bool?)user?.IsBot).GetValueOrDefault())`

Comment: You could just do `if (user?.IsBot == true)`. Also you don't need to cast to bool? because like you said it is already a nullable bool.

Comment: @ckuri: You are right, thanks. However, if you want to call `GetValueOrDefault` you would still need to put parentheses around `user?.IsBot`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to check for bot if the user object isnt null. And if the user object is null, you have to check for the consequent things like GetClient, GetData etc.

I would write it as :

```
 static bool IsValid(User user)
 {
    // if the user is not null and IsBot flag is true, return true
    if (user != null && user.IsBot)
       return true;

    // either the user is null or the IsBot flag is false here, hence check the following calls
    return !(user.GetClient() == null || user.GetClient().GetData() == null || user.GetClient().GetData().CurrentRoomId != _room.RoomId);
 }
```

Please note that you will have to change the code as per your requirement, whether you want true or false to return in which condition.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternate and functional approach on which you define rules using lambdas and then you check that all rules are `true`:

```
private Func<User, bool>[] Requires = { get; } = new [] 
{ 
      user => user?.isBot == true,
      // Comparing the expression returning Nullable<bool> with true
      // implicitly converts it to bool
      user => (user?.GetClient()?.GetData()?.CurrentRoomId == room.RoomId) == true
}

public bool IsValid(User user) => Requires.All(r => r(user))
```

That could be also refactored as follows:

```
public bool isValid(User user) => 
    user?.isBot == true 
    && 
    (user?.GetClient()?.GetData()?.CurrentRoomId == room.RoomId) == true
```

Comment: @FCin You know that this is subjective. It's a declarative approach on which you clearly see that you can add rules to check an user. It's a functional simplification of specification pattern :D

Comment: My problem with this approach is that the rules are mixing null checks - which have nothing to do with the logic - with logical checks that come from the business domain. If you go this route with the specification pattern, each rule should be self contained. This is not the case here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'll continue the discussion tonight, I need to go

Comment: @DanielHilgarth For me, null checks should be *contracts* but since Code Contracts are deprecated I don't think about them anymore. In the other hand, you know that C# 8 will introduce non-nullable references which, in fact, they're a replacement to `Contract.Requires(x != null)` precondition.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth In the other hand, I understand that your concern is that `user.IsBot` woudn't work without previously defining `user != null` so you advocate for `user != null && user.IsBot` or `user?.IsBot == true`